# CAS-Toolbox : Get Nested Group from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are using Cas-Toolbox for our intranet.

We manage to get LDAP attribute via CAS and send it to the intranet app :

```
<bean id="adAttribRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.ldap.LdapPersonAttributeDao">
    <property name="baseDN" value="DC=main,DC=cobaltgroup,DC=com"/>
    <property name="queryTemplate" value="{0}"/>
    <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="yes"/>
    <property name="usernameAttributeProvider">
        <bean class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.SimpleUsernameAttributeProvider">
            <constructor-arg value="sAMAccountName"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
    <map>
        <!-- Mapping beetween LDAP entry's attributes (key) and Principal"s (value) -->
        <entry key="cn" value="Name"/>
        <entry key="mail" value="Email"/>
    </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to know if it is possible to get groups the user belongs to.
I tried the AD attribute "memberOf", but it returns only "first level" of group membership

Example :

- User is in groupA
- groupA is in groupB

MemberOf returns only groupA

I want to get groupA AND groupB

With the following filter, ldapsearch it is easy:

```
'(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x))'
```

But I don't know how to make it work with CAS-Toolbox

- Is there a way of creating custom attribute mapping using a LDAP Query ?
- Is there a constructed AD attribute that already give the right answer ?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Do u found any solution to this?